# Update all keys of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object

how to update all keys an object by getting an array witch have keys that we want
Example :

```
const data = {
0 : {text : 'hello'},
1 : {text : 'hi'},
2 : {text : 'hay!'} 
}
function arrayCombine(keys , values){
...logics
}
console.log(arrayCombine([10 , 20 , 37] , data));

// resault
{
10 : {text : 'hello'},
20 : {text : 'hi'},
37 : {text : 'hay!'} 
}
```

This function gets an array and an object then performs an operation on the object and change all the keys of the object to that array's element.
In the php we have a built-in function witch is called [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)
.

Comment: It is not so clear what exactly do you want to do here. You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, below logic should works

```js
const data = {
  0: { text: 'hello' },
  1: { text: 'hi' },
  2: { text: 'hay!' },
};
function arrayCombine(keys, values) {
  const valuesArray = Object.values(values);
  let result = {};
  keys.forEach((item, index) => (result[item] = valuesArray[index]));
  return result;
}
console.log(arrayCombine([10, 20, 37], data));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = {
  0: {
    text: 'hello'
  },
  1: {
    text: 'hi'
  },
  2: {
    text: 'hay!'
  },
};

function arrayCopy(keys, values) {
  const valuesArray = Object.values(values);
  return keys.map((e, i) => ({
    [e]: valuesArray[i]
  }));
}
console.log(arrayCopy([10, 20, 37], data));
```